# Trying to understand how this webpage uses javascript to produce a growth rate

Tags: javascript, excel, math

I'm very limited in my JS and even mathematics knowledge for that matter so I turn to you. I'm using a site linked [here](http://www.citypopulation.de/php/nigeria-admin.php) to find annual population growth rates for individual Nigerian states. When you click on a state, say Abia, it will give you the annual growth rate. I'm trying to figure out the exact formula that they're using to produce said growth rates. [Here](http://www.citypopulation.de/js/cp_data_m.js) is the .js file that containing the code to do this. I believe the block we want is this:

```
cp.data.computeAnnualChange=function(a,b,c,d){
   if(!a||!b)return null;a=this.dateDiffInYears(a,b);
   return 0<c&&0<a&&0<d?Math.round(1E4*(Math.exp(Math.log(d/c)/a)-1))/100:null};
   cp.data.INT_MODE="i";
```

Some context: The formula is supposed to take the population of a state from 1991 and the population from 2006 and provide you with the annual rate of growth. I recognize that basic equation on line 4, it's a geometric growth rate. I can make that in excel, but when I do the number I come up with is about .13 percent off, which is significant. My ultimate goal is to make this into a formula I can use in excel.

Comment: It seems to be missing a comma or operator after `1E4`, isn't it?

Comment: @pnuts you've got it! I hadn't taken into account that they might be counting partial years. I was using the whole number 14. The first census was 11/26/91 and the second was 3/21/06 which is 14.32 years. I plugged that into the equation and it came out to be the same as what the site was producing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question since someone's comment helped me figure it out.

Basically, I had it right with the formula I posted in the original question, it's just that I wasn't precise enough with the data range. The two censuses were 14.32 years apart and I was just using 14.

The correct formula is (EXP((LN(pn/p0)/14.32))-1)   where pn and p0 are the newest and oldest censuses respectively.